# TCPDF: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1 error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, tcpdf

I've been using TCPDF.
In my local machine, TCPDF works fine, but it throws an error in the actual server. The error message is as follows.

> Message: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>
> Message: getimagesize(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> getimagesize(http:/test.com/images/sample.jpg): failed to open stream: operation failed

If I understand them right, this application couldn't verify the SSL certificate of the server.

So, following [this example](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/), I put get the signature in the following way.

```
$pdf  = new TCPDF();
$certificate = '/blahblah/certs/certificate.crt';
$pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'pdfgen', '', 2, []);
```

Still, I'm seeing the same error.

When TCPDF throws this `"SSL operation failed with code 1"` error, what does it mean?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $pdf->setSignature() is adding a digital signature to you document. It has nothing to do with the ssl error, when loading the (remote) image. Verify the URL of the image. You could test the URL from shell of your server (e.g. curl, openssl s_client). Also: you are using http not https (getimagesize).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using the library `html2pdf` that needs to get the image size through the PHP function `getsizeimage()` and my image URL was with `https` so I solved by specifying in my `php.ini` file the SSL certificate.

```
[openssl]
openssl.cafile="/etc/nginx/tls/yourCert.crt"
```

Answer (score 0):

or maybe you try HTTP locally and then change to HTTPS on the live server

Answer (score 0):

This Problem take me hours! I have a ngnix Server. The only thing I had to do is to paste the content of  "mykey.ca" file at the end of the "mykey.crt" file, save it as new file "newBothKey.crt" and set this file in "/etc/nginx/sites-available"

```
listen 443 ssl;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/.ssl/sitename/newBothKey.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/.ssl/sitename/mykey.key;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
```

Don't forget to restart nginx:

```
sudo systmctl restart nginix
```